# How to avoid recompilation of output file in Makefile if all sources are up to date

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a makefile in my c++ project

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -c
SRC=src
SOURCES=main.cpp ... # and all other .cpp files
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
USERNAME=denisand
LIBS=-lpthread

all: compile

compile: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(USERNAME) $(LIBS)

run:
    ./$(USERNAME)

doc:
    doxygen Doxyfile

main.o: $(SRC)/main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

%.o: $(SRC)/%.cpp $(SRC)/%.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o -R ./doc $(USERNAME)
```

So it recompiles source files (.o) only if needed, but compiles output file (.exe) every time, which is not desired. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour? I'm not sure if it should be on duty of Makefile or some g++ flag.

Comment: you are not explicitly using tne true dependencies in the line `compile: $(OBJECTS)`, it should be `$(USERNAME): $(OBJECTS)`.

Answer (score 2):

> So it recompiles source files (.o) only if needed, but compiles output file (.exe) every time, which is not desired. Is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

Yes.

> I'm not sure if it should be on duty of Makefile or some g++ flag.

`g++` runs if and when `make` executes a recipe that includes a `g++` command.  It is your makefile that should be corrected.

The problem is that your executable is not among the targets you provide rules for or ever ask `make` to build.  Building that file is merely a side effect of building the phony `compile` target, so `make` never even considers whether it is out of date.  Instead, it considers whether `compile` is out of date, and that will always be the case if there is no such file in the working directory.

Make the executable an actual target.  In fact, I see no reason not to convert the `compile` rule into a rule for the executable:

**Old:**

```
all: compile

compile: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(USERNAME) $(LIBS)
```

**New:**

```
all: $(USERNAME)

$(USERNAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)
```